# python regular expressions does ordering of alternatives matter for speed/choosing between alternatives

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match (and remove) any of 4000 expressions.

If I put the most common matches at the front will that speed matching (or is it undefined)

although typically exclusive, I sometimes have default cases: 'ax*|a(0-9)|', ie 'a', but I want a greedy match if possible. is it sufficient to reorder  'a(0-9)|ax*' or is this not guaranteed by the specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does ordering of alternatives matter for speed/choosing between alternatives?

Yes, it does. Alternative groups are analyzed from left to right, and that happens at each position in the input string.

Thus, putting the most common matches at the start is already a boost.

When speaking about *unanchored* alternation lists in NFA regex (as in Python), it is important that alternatives that can match at the same location should be ordered in such a way that **the longest comes first** because otherwise a shorter alternative will always "win", and you may end up with `xxxone` when matching with `some|someone` -> `xxx` wanting to get `xxx` from `someone`.

Comment: do you have any reference that documents this?

Comment: The [main one here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): *The regex engine is eager. It stops searching as soon as it finds a valid match.*

Comment: I could not upvote the question yesterday since I ran out of votes - done now.